jsPDF doesn't render the whole div i'm trying to export
I have a big scrollable table in the content body and i'm trying to save it as PDF
table
this is the code i'm using to save the pdf (i use this in other parts of the code for single page exports and it works fine)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js "></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

function export() {
    const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
    var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');
  
    var elementHTML = document.getElementById('table_id');
    doc.html(elementHTML, {
        callback: function (doc) {
            // Save the PDF
            window.open(doc.output('bloburl')); // use this to debug
        },  
            x: 5,
            y: 10,
            width: 290, //target width in the PDF document
            windowWidth: 1150, //window width in CSS pixels
        });
}

this is the pdf generated
pdf
As you can see it cuts the table and the second page is blank
I want to render the whole table. i zoomed out to let you see how many pieces are cut out in the export
full table
Hope someone can help me, Thank you

Thank you for your answer! I added the pages i need and divided the table in smaller tables so i can print each one in a diffrent page. But I'm not able to set the content of the new pages, it creates the first page with the right content but the other pages are blank. i tried:
doc.addPage();
doc.html(id_table2, ....);
